# Woocommerce shop page not showing all products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This is my website http://www.buttlights.com/shop. Only 27 out of 500 products are showing and there is no pagination menu as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's very hard to debug without seeing your backend.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. Some columns in product description were causing the error